# How to interrupt blocking accept() call in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I'm trying to exit an `accept()` call after a timeout occurs using an `alarm()` signal. The signal registers as excepted but isn't interrupting the blocking `accept()` process. How can I make the signal break the loop or interrupt the blocking process?

```
volatile sig_atomic_t time_out_flag = false;

void handleSig(int sig)
{
    std::cout << "signal\n";
    time_out_flag = true;
    return;
}

void Server::start(ClientHandler &ch) // throw(const char *)
{
    t = new std::thread([&] { // Main thread
        sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        sockaddr.sin_port = htons(_port);

        if (bind(_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr)) < 0) // Bind socket (socket, sockaddr, addrlen)
            throw("Failed to bind to port.\n");

        if (listen(_socket, 2) < 0) // Passivly listen on socket (socket, backlog aka max users queued)
            throw("Failed to listen on socket.\n");

        auto addrlen = sizeof(sockaddr);
        signal(SIGALRM, handleSig); // What to do after alarm(k)
        while (!time_out_flag)
        {
            alarm(3);
            int connection = accept(_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&sockaddr, (socklen_t *)&addrlen);
            if (connection < 0) {
                throw("accept() error\n");
            }
            alarm(0);
            ch.handle(connection);
        }
        std::cout << "after";
    });
}
```

I would really like to work with `accept()` and not `select()` if possible.

**UPDATE**

I've changed `signal()` to `sigaction()` as was recommended, but `accept()` continues blocking the thread. This is the revised code:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t alarmed = 0;

void handle_alarm(int)
{
    std::cout << "alarm\n";
    alarmed = 1;
    return;
}

void Server::start(ClientHandler &ch) // throw(const char *)
{
    sigset_t mask;
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGALRM);

    if (pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, nullptr) < 0)
        throw("sigaction pthread failed\n");

#ifdef USE_SIGACTION
    // Set up sigaction() with alarmer
    struct sigaction sigbreak;
    std::memset(&sigbreak, 0, sizeof sigbreak);
    sigbreak.sa_handler = &handle_alarm;

    if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &sigbreak, NULL) != 0)
        throw("sigaction() failed\n");

#else
    if (signal(SIGALRM, handle_alarm) == SIG_ERR)
        throw("signal() failed\n");
#endif

    t = new std::thread([&] { // Main thread
        if (pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, nullptr) < 0)
            std::cout << "alarmos\n";

        struct sockaddr_in server_sockaddr;
        struct sockaddr_in sockaddr = {0};
        sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        sockaddr.sin_port = htons(_port);
        if (bind(_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr)) < 0) // Bind socket (socket, sockaddr, addrlen)
            throw("Failed to bind to port.\n");

        if (listen(_socket, 2) < 0) // Passivly listen on socket (socket, backlog aka max users queued)
            throw("Failed to listen on socket.\n");

        auto addrlen = sizeof(sockaddr);
        while (1)
        {
            if (alarmed)
                return;
            try
            {
                alarm(3);
                int connection = accept(_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&sockaddr, (socklen_t *)&addrlen);
                if (alarmed)
                    return;
                if (connection == -1)
                    throw("accept() error\n");
                alarm(0);
                ch.handle(connection);
            }

            catch (const char *msg)
            {
                throw(msg);
            }
        }
    });
    alarm(3);
}
```

**UPDATE + SOLUTION**

defining `USE_SIGACTION` does the trick and interrupts `accept()` as suggested in the answer.

Comment: This is exactly what `select` and the variants, poll, epoll, etc are good at. Why not use one of them?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The instructor explicitly asked for `alarm()` as part of the solution to a timeout.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you mean by `"...the interrupt isn't working"`.

Comment: You could use [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). See also [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html), [signalfd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html). Your `SIGALRM` signal handler would set a global `volatile sigatomic_t flag`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `signal()` installs signal handlers in such a way that syscalls like `accept()` are resumed after a signal is caught*. Use `sigaction()` instead to disable that behavior:

```cpp
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//#define USE_SIGACTION

volatile sig_atomic_t alarmed = 0;

void handle_alarm(int) {
  alarmed = 1;
}

int main(void) {
  sigset_t mask;
  sigemptyset(&mask);
  sigaddset(&mask, SIGALRM);

  if (pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, nullptr) < 0) {
    std::perror("pthread_sigmask");
    return 1;
  }

#ifdef USE_SIGACTION
  struct sigaction alarmer;
  std::memset(&alarmer, 0, sizeof alarmer);
  alarmer.sa_handler = handle_alarm;
  // For resumable syscalls you'd have
  // alarmer.sa_flags = SA_RESTARTT;
  // but we don't want that.
  if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &alarmer, nullptr) < 0) {
    std::perror("sigaction");
    return 1;
  }
  std::cout << "Using sigaction()\n";
#else
  if (signal(SIGALRM, handle_alarm) == SIG_ERR) {
    std::perror("signal");
    return 1;
  }
  std::cout << "Using signal()\n";
#endif

  std::thread t{[&mask](){
      char dummy[5];

      if (pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, nullptr) < 0) {
        perror("pthread_sigmask");
        std::exit(1);
      }

      std::cout << "Waiting...\n";
      auto bytes = read(0, dummy, sizeof dummy);
      if (bytes < 0) {
        std::perror("read");
        if (alarmed) {
          std::cerr << "SIGALRM was caught.\n";
          return;
        }
        std::exit(1);
      }
    }};

  alarm(1);
  t.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Example usage:

```
$ g++ -pthread -O -Wall -Wextra -DUSE_SIGACTION foo.cpp
$ ./a.out                                     
Using sigaction()
Waiting...
read: Interrupted system call
SIGALRM was caught.
$ g++ -pthread -O -Wall -Wextra foo.cpp
$ ./a.out                     
Using signal()
Waiting...
^C
```

---

Notes on `signal()`: Whether it turns on restartable syscalls or not isn't specified by POSIX, and different OSes can and do differ. The Linux/Glibc behavior is described in its [`signal(2)` man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html):

> By default, in glibc 2 and later, the `signal()` wrapper function does not invoke the kernel system call.  Instead, it calls `sigaction(2)` using flags that supply BSD semantics.  This default behavior is provided as long as a suitable feature test macro is defined: `_BSD_SOURCE` on glibc 2.19 and earlier or `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` in glibc 2.19 and later.  (By default, these macros are defined; see `feature_test_macros(7)` for details.) If such a feature test macro is not defined, then `signal()` provides System V semantics.

BSD semantics include restarting syscalls, System V ones do not. The best approach, as suggested by the documentation, is to just never use `signal()` and stick with `sigaction()` and friends.

On threads and signals: When a multi-threaded application receives a signal that isn't directed at a particular thread, it is delivered to a random thread that doesn't have that signal blocked. So this code first blocks `SIGALRM` and then unblocks it in the example blocking thread. If you don't do something like this, it might not be your `accept()` that gets interrupted, but something in a different thread.

Comment: This seems to lead to the same result somehow. I've updated my post.

Comment: @Nix Are you defining `USE_SIGACTION` somewhere?

Comment: completely went over my head. It works perfectly once defined, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without `select()` you can just close socket in another thread for example. In this case, the `accept()` will end. But this case is not Normal.

By the way your code has issue with throw exceptions. In this situation within thread your program will be terminated. To avoid that you should write try-catch inside thread. For example:

```
t = new std::thread([&] { // Main thread
    sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sockaddr.sin_port = htons(_port);
try
{
 ....
}
catch(const char* msg)
{
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}});
```

It is good practice to use exception classes from namespace std instead of strings.

Comment: I think that would lead to undefined behavor - unless there is documentation explicitly stating a defined behavior for this scenario.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I agree with you.